# What are the algorithms for integer programming in which constraints are dependent?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

What are some ways to deal with dependent constraints in integer programming?

For example, suppose I want to maximize $x+3y+2z$ subject to (i) $x+y<=3$ and (ii) if $y+z>=2$ then $x+z<=6$.

Are there any theories/algorithms on this type of integer programming?

Comment: you can try to divide it to two IP problem, and it looks like the first one with the only constraint $x+y\leq 3$ will be unbounded, because $z$ is unrestricted. The second one will be with all three constraints and it looks like appropriate IP problem.

Comment: I do not get it. How does your suggestion deal with the dependency in the 2nd constraint, i.e. if y+z>=2 then x+z<=6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can model certain logical constraints like "if-then" statements using binary inequalities.

For your problem, you could introduce the binary variable $w$, which can only take on values of $0$ or $1$.

Then your "if $y+z \geq 2$ then $x+z \leq 6$" constraint can be implemented as the following:

$$
\begin{align}
y + z - 1 &\leq M(1 - w), \\
x + z - 6 &\leq Mw,
\end{align}
$$ 
where $M$ is some sufficiently large constant.

Why does this work?  If $y+z \geq 2$, then the first constraint forces the value of $w$ to be $0$, which causes the second inequality to be equivalent to $x + z \leq 6$.  On the other hand, if $y+z \leq 1$, then the first constraint doesn't force anything about the value of $w$, which means that second constraint allows $x+z \leq 6$ or $x + z \geq 7$.  (I'm assuming that all variables are integers, since you mentioned that you're doing integer programming.)

For more on linear and integer programming models with logical constraints, see [Section 3.3 of Rader's *Deterministic Operations Research*](http://books.google.com/books?id=VqjhIZhsITsC&pg=PA94&dq=deterministic%20operations%20research%20rader%20logical%20constraints&hl=en&sa=X&ei=98NHT8Qq6aOJAry29NoN&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).  Other texts on linear and integer programming sometimes discuss modeling with logical constraints as well.

Comment: Thanks,Mike! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @pegausbupt: I'm glad it was helpful!